# Having issues using order function in R

Tags: r, function, statistics

My data.frame is `stateData` and when I execute `stateData[order(stateData$"heart failure"),]`, with `heart failure` being a column name, I'm getting my dataframe back with the `heart failure` column having increasing values like this:

```
10.0, 10.1, 10.3, 10.7, 15.0, 15.1, 15.9, 8.1, 8.3, 8.9, 9.0, 9.1
```

Here are details:
`dput(head(stateData)) 
heart failure = structure(c(97L, 44L, 25L, 6L, 52L, 57L ), .Label = c("10.0", "7.2", "7.3", "7.4", "7.5", "7.6", "7.7", "7.8", "7.9", "8.0", "8.1", "8.2", "8.3", "8.4", "8.5", "8.6", "8.7", "8.8", "8.9", "9.0", "9.1", "9.2", "9.3", "9.4", "9.5", "9.6", "9.7", "9.8", "9.9", "Not Available"), class = "factor"),`

Why is it not sorting it all the way?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Edit: Here is my solution! I got it, thanks for all of the advice!

```
stateData[,"heart failure"] <- as.numeric(levels(stateData["heart failure"])[stateData[,"heart failure"]]) 
sortedData <- stateData[order(stateData[,"heart failure"]),]
```

Comment: Without seeing your data, my best guess is that your "heart failure" entries are characters.  But, you should provide a reproducible example (hint: provide the output of `dput(head(stateData))` or a subset of the columns to make a minimal reproducible example).

Comment: @beginneR - that will throw an error as the interpreter will see `stateData$heart` and then freak out because there is some extra text just hanging around.

Comment: @user1047260 as you can see, the "Not Available" value caused the data to be stored as a factor instead of as a numeric value. You might try `stateData$"heart failure" <- as.numeric(stateData$"heart failure")`

Comment: That is a malformed factor variable. You need to review your data management procedures. The problem likely starts at the initial data input steps.

Answer (score 0):

The column stateData$"heart failure" is a factor, so when R sorts it, it puts it in alphabetical order. If you want the data sorted numerically, try this:

```
 stateData$"heart failure" <- as.numeric(levels(stateData$"heart failure"))[stateData$"heart failure"]
 stateData[order(stateData$"heart failure"),]
```

Comment: close, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information

Comment: I suppose it could be called "close" if it weren't simply wrong and that the correct answer is in the R-FAQ.

Comment: Ah, I see your point, @GSee. I wasn't thinking about the ranking problem. user1047260: I like your answer. I don't know how you're reading in your data, but using colClasses when you do so and setting the data type as you read it in might eliminate the need for it. i.e. read.csv("Data.csv", colClasses=c("character", "numeric"))

Comment: Laura, please edit your answer per the FAQ, i.e. `as.numeric(as.character(....))`